# How to use fopen or fsockopen to get feedback

Tags: php, fopen, fsockopen

I need your help to create simple php code with fopen or fsockopen

I want to check ips by http://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_xx.xx.xx.xx
and get feedback

For example :

The user ip is 127.0.0.1

Now i will use fopen or fsockopen to ckeck if the projecthoneypot.org have any info  about it or  not

http://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_127.0.0.1

if "don't have data on this IP currently" echo "No Date" else "Data Was Found"

Please help

Comment: and get date? What date?

Comment: Well `fsockopen` would be the worst way to create a HTTP-Request. Either use [curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) or [`file_get_contents`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). The later requires `allow_url_fopen` to be enabled.

Comment: Jan Dragsbaek just a minute.i will improve the Q.thanks

Comment: Thank you vstm. i will try to search to find how i can do that.Regards

Comment: Does anyone have a simple code i can use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... simple code:

```
$response = file_get_contents("http://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_127.0.0.1");
$match = preg_match("/don't have data on this IP currently/i", $response);

if($match) {
    echo "No Date";
} else {
    echo "Data Was Found";
}
```

Or with curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_127.0.0.1',
    CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$match = preg_match("/don't have data on this IP currently/i", $response);

if($match) {
    echo "No Date";
} else {
    echo "Data Was Found";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much vstm ! . My Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using fsockopen as it allows you to easily define a timeout. However it does require sockets to be enabled in the config.

Comment: Thank you Sudhir. do you have any simple php code can do that ? Regards